# How to find difference between multiple probability distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions

I have few `vectors` (of length `1000`) representing **frequency of 1000 elements for different situations**.

e.g. Vector for situation 1 is

`s1=(12, 0, 3, 4, 0, ...., 10)`

and is of length `1000` (as there are **1000 distinct elements**).

I have 10 such vectors `s1, s2, ..., s10`.

How do I statistically show that the probability distributions over all `1000` elements for these `10` vectors are **significantly different**?

e.g. One way would be to use `KL-Divergence`. Also, how to use `KL-Divergence` for such `10` distributions?

Comment: You need a probability model in order to assess "significance." Could you therefore provide a model or explain how these vectors arise?

Comment: Would the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test make sense?  You'd have to do it 45 times to test all of them relative to one another, but hey, that's what computers are for, right?